# Password prompt for email

Tags: mac

Is there a way to add a password prompt when opening email app on a mac? To stop others from opening the email program on a shared computer. Basically i dont want anyone to open the email program without a password.

Answer (score 3):

Separate user accounts are for that purpose. If you really have to use a shared account then do it but create additional one just for your **Mail** app.

Answer (score 0):

slick is right. You would have to create another user account and switch to it to read mail **if you have to use mail.app.**

If you can use webmail with that account instead of the mail.app just don't let the browser save the password for your webmail login and you can securely get into your mail under the same account. heck you could even use a "Private Window" so no one else with access can read the cache or history.